# Problema em identificar a vez no Jogo da Velha

Tags: java, swing

Eu estou tentando implementar o Jogo da Velha em Java com Swing, mas o meu contador que define as jogadas, não muda, então exibe sempre a mesma jogada:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Velha extends JFrame implements ActionListener, MouseListener {

    private JPanel painel;
    private final int LARGURA = 480;
    private final int ALTURA = 320;
    private Rectangle rect[];
    private boolean colidiu = false;

    private int posX, posY;
    private Timer timer;

    private int contador;

    public Velha() {

        //Cria uma nova instancia da classe Rectangle;
        rect = new Rectangle[9];

        timer = new Timer(6, this);
        timer.start();
        contador = 0;

        painel = new JPanel() {

            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponent(g);
                desenhar(g);
            }

            public void desenhar(Graphics g) {

                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
                g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
                g2d.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                for(int linha = 0; linha < 3; linha++) {
                    for(int coluna = 0; coluna < 3; coluna++) {
                        int xWidth = (LARGURA / 3);
                        int yHeigth = (ALTURA / 3);
                        g2d.drawRect(xWidth * linha, yHeigth * coluna, xWidth, yHeigth);

                        rect[linha * 3 + coluna] = new Rectangle(xWidth * linha, yHeigth * coluna, xWidth, yHeigth);
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        painel.addMouseListener(this);
        painel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        painel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(LARGURA, ALTURA));
        getContentPane().add(painel);
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        if(colidiu) {

            Graphics grapichs = getGraphics();
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) grapichs;
            g2d.setColor(Color.RED);

            if(contador % 2 == 0) {
                g2d.drawLine(posX - 10, posY - 15, posX + 40, posY + 60);
                g2d.drawLine(posX - 10, posY + 60, posX + 40, posY - 10);
                return;
            } else {
                g2d.drawOval(posX - 30, posY, 60, 60);
            }

            //Incrementa quantidade de jogadas;
            contador++;
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Velha().setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent e) {

        for(int i=0; i<9; i++) {
            Rectangle eClick = new Rectangle(e.getX(), e.getY(), (LARGURA / 3), (ALTURA / 3));
            if(rect[i].getBounds().intersects(eClick)) {
                System.out.println("Retangulo: " + (i + 1));
                colidiu = true; 
                posX = (int) rect[i].getCenterX();
                posY = (int) rect[i].getCenterY();
                break; 
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent e) {}

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(java.awt.event.MouseEvent e) {}

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(java.awt.event.MouseEvent e) {}

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(java.awt.event.MouseEvent e) {}
}
```

O problema seria em: `if(contador % 2 == 0)`, mas não consigo resolver.

Comment: O contador é para identificar a vez de qual jogador é?

Comment: Seria sim isso,.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aqui funcionou apenas alterando a variável `colidiu` para `false` após  haver uma colisão, o problema nem era o contador:

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    if(colidiu) {

        Graphics grapichs = getGraphics();
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) grapichs;
        g2d.setColor(Color.RED);

        if(contador % 2 == 0) {
            g2d.drawLine(posX - 10, posY - 15, posX + 40, posY + 60);
            g2d.drawLine(posX - 10, posY + 60, posX + 40, posY - 10);
        } else {
            g2d.drawOval(posX - 30, posY, 60, 60);
        }

        //Incrementa quantidade de jogadas;
        contador++;
        colidiu = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Funcionou Diego, você saberia dizer como aplicar o efeito de anti aliasing nos desenhos( X e O)?

Comment: @Paulo pela sua abordagem, não acho uma boa pratica, pois você está manipulando o Graphics em varios lugares diferentes e já aplicou o anti aliasing, o ideal é arrumar uma forma de manipular ele só no paintcomponents. O problema é que se eu sugerir a forma ideal, eu teria que reescrever seu código inteiro, seria inviavel. Tente analisar por essa minha sugestão, ai se tiver duvidas, pergunte aqui no site que a gente te ajuda ;)